# What does checkDate(date)[0] mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

1. Can anyone explain what is meant by `!checkDate(date)[0]`?
2. Is it true that the function `checkDate(date)` passes the Javascript date object as an argument? Is that the case that the JavaScript object doesn't need to be initialized when it pass as argument?

```
$("form").on("submit",function(event) {
var date;
try {
    date = $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", $("#date").val());
 } catch (error) { }
if (!date) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("Please provide a valid date.");
}
if (date && !checkDate(date)[0]) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("Cannot select a weekend or Tuesday for Dr.Smith.");
}
});

function checkDate(date) {
  var isWeekday = date.getDay() > 0 && date.getDay() < 6;
  if ($("#doctor").val() === "Smith") {
     return [isWeekday && date.getDay() != 2];
   } else {
     return [isWeekday];
   }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `checkDate()` returns an array. `checkDate(date)[0]` returns the first element of the array. In this case, `true` if the date is a weekday (and not a Tuesday if it's Dr. Smith)
2. `checkDate()` *receives* a `Date` as its only argument. That `Date` is passed in from the code above, where it was initialized by `$.datepicker.parseDate()`

Answer (score 4):

1. `!checkDate(date)[0]`

   - `checkDate()` returns an array, containing a single element, which is a boolean.
   - `checkDate()[0]` would access that boolean element.
   - `!checkDate()[0]` negates that boolean element (in other words, if the boolean was `true`, the result of the above expression would be `false`, and vice-versa).
2. `checkDate()` accepts a JavaScript Date object as it's parameter, yes.